# Travis CI - Failed to read encrypted key from store - Invalid Keystore format - Android

Tags: android, encryption, travis-ci, keystore

I've created encrypted keystore file. I'm using Travis CI for building and to generate apk. Its showing following error.

> Error:   Failed to read key [secure] from store
>   "app/[secure].jks.enc": Invalid keystore format

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Thanks,
Kamal

Answer (score 0):

In your `build.gradle`, your should specify the `storeFile` to the original keystore file name, which not contains the suffix ".enc", because Travis will decrypt it for you:

```
android {
    // ...
    signingConfigs {
        release
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    def isRunningOnTravis = System.getenv("CI") == "true"

    if (isRunningOnTravis) {
        // configure keystore
        signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file("../myshape.jks") // <-- here
        signingConfigs.release.storePassword = System.getenv("keystore_password")
        signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = System.getenv("keystore_alias")
        signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = System.getenv("keystore_alias_password")
    }
}
```